# Writing a function for class and vscode saying argument not declared even though I am using it

Tags: arrays, function, arguments, declaration, nested-object

Im a newbie to this coding thing and cant get over this hump in my practice problem. is says in my parameter when I have over it "is declared but  value never read". I tried making it equal to something else but nothing. this is the function:

```
function pluck(arr,value) {
var obj = arr;
let val = [];
let name = value;
for (let i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    val.push(`${obj[i].name}`);
}

return val;
```

//this is part of my tss practice problems, i just need some more guidance on this. "value" is the thing im having problems with.

I tried renaming the "value" in the argument to "name" so i could use it in my obj[i].name function since im dealing with an array with objects nested inside. but "name" became the new thing not used.

Comment: You are using the parameter `value` to initialise `name`, but you are not using the `name` variable.

Comment: I'd guess what you actually want is [`val.push(arr[i][name])`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1048572)

Comment: thanks for replying Bergi, to give you some more information, this function is for an object, nested in an array.

Comment: Yes, I already inferred that from [the name `pluck`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pluck+%5Bjs%5D). Does my suggestion work for you?

Comment: YES! I didn't know that it would run the same as "obj[i].value". I ended up doing away with "let name=value" entirely. Thanks so much! I'll try to implement this in other functions I'm stuck on with similar problems.